# Elixir: recursive generators

Tags: recursion, stream, elixir, generator

Is it possible to build a Python style recursive generator with Elixir? Something like this:

```
def traverse(parent_dir):
    dirs, files = get_dirs_and_files_as_lists(parent_dir)

    for d in dirs:
        yield from traverse(d)

    for f in files:
        yield f
```

For all the files to be processed linearly, without overhead implied by an eager list of indefinite length:

```
for f in traverse(dir):
    process(f)
```

This, or some working equivalent, should be possible using streams; unfortunately, I have no idea how.

I want something like this, just lazy:

```
def traverse_eagerly(parent_dir) do
  {dirs, files} = get_dirs_and_files_as_lists(parent_dir)

  for x <- dirs do
    traverse_eagerly(x)
  end
  |> Enum.concat()
  |> Enum.concat(files)
end
```

Comment: Your question is tempting me to answer "How do I traverse a directory", but that's not what you asked :P Maybe I'll ask it myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution appears to be trivial: replace `Enum` with `Stream`.

```
def traverse_lazily(parent_dir) do
  {dirs, files} = get_dirs_and_files_as_lists(parent_dir)

  for x <- dirs do
    traverse_lazily(x)
  end
  |> Stream.concat()
  |> Stream.concat(files)
end
```

The following works as expected:

```
s = traverse_lazily(a_dir_of_choice)

for x <- s, do: whatever_you_please(x)
```

Very nice of the language. As fine a solution as you would wish for. Unless I'm missing something, that is :) . Comments are welcome!

Comment: `Stream.flat_map(&traverse_lazily/1)`

Comment: Oh, a nice touch. Thank you, [Kabie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260985/kabie)!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `Stream` here, but if you want, here is it:

```rb
defmodule Traverse do
  @spec traverse(root :: binary(), yielder :: (binary() -> any())) ::
     :ok | {:error, posix()}
  def traverse(root, yielder) do
    # https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/File.html?#ls/1
    with {:ok, list} <- File.ls(root) do
      list
      |> Stream.each(fn file_or_dir ->
        if File.dir?(file_or_dir),
          do: traverse(file_or_dir, yielder), # TCO
          else: yielder.(file_or_dir)
      end)
      |> Stream.run()
    end
  end
end
```

And call it like:

```rb
Traverse.traverse(".", &IO.inspect/1)
```

Comment: Nb: TCO = Tail Call Optimization

Comment: TCO does not have a lot to do with the case in point. Yes, one can traverse the tree Pascal fashion passing the handler as a parameter. Recursion goes no deeper than the tree depth, BTW. I'm asking about a tree node generator which is functionally, if not syntactically, equivalent to the Python solution. It's an illustration, not a request for a directory tree walker.

Comment: I do not get what the issue is. Pass an accumulator to `yielder` function and collect whatever you want. You should not try to apply elixir syntax to python solutions, Erlang and hence elixir always have a better way of doing things.

Comment: But of course. It's all about having *my* wishes in a nice and idiomatic way.